# How to change separator for csv file which is ',' now . I am using openCSV jar

Tags: sqlite

I am beginner in android and want to import data from csv file into Sqlite database in android.
I first inserting actual data in a csv file, but some where I need comma(,). So I want to change separator.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question whether you don't know how to change commas into some other separator, or you don't know how to tell sqlite about the new separators... I'll assume it is the former and that you have a some Unix-y computer available.

You can transliterate all commas in a file into colons, for example, using "tr" like this:

```
tr ',' ':' < oldfile.csv > newfile.csv
```

Here is an example with a simple string, and the output:

```
echo hi,there,my,friend | tr ',' ':'
hi:there:my:friend
```

Or you can use sed, like this:

```
echo hi,there,my,friend | sed 's/,/:/g'
hi:there:my:friend
```

That says "substitute (s) comma with colon, globally (g) throughout file"